# Specific crash log in Xcode Archives

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, amazon-web-services

My app is currently in its beta stage and I'm using TestFlight for general testing. I keep getting reports on sudden crashes in the app and right after the sudden crash the app crash in every restart.

I wasn't able to recreate this in the Xcode simulator so I turned to the crash logs in the Archive.

The following error shows:

`SwiftUI: StoredLocationBase.BeginUpdate.combine<A>(with:) + 824 (Thread 0)`

Each and every crash described above got this error linked to it.

My app has users and a "remember me" function using AWS, maybe it's something with that? How can I figure out where this error can come from?

Another note that might be useful (maybe?): I just got the same bug on my own device with the TestFlight version of my app on it. My device runs iOS 14.0.1 and the Xcode I'm using is 11.6 (which can't run iOS 14 on the simulator), maybe somehow the version difference is the cause?